# Applying jQuery function to dynamically added item

Tags: jquery

When adding a new textbox via jQuery append() function it appears jQuery is unable to apply a function to that textbox;

```
            $("#ulList").append("<li><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close remove\"/><em class=\"selectedWord\">" + selectedWord + "</em><input class=\"acf acfb-input ac_input\" type=\"text\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\" value = '' /></li>");

            $("#" + name).autoCompletefb();
```

The function I am attempting to apply to the newly added input is the autoCompletefb() method  but it seems jQuery is unable to find the newly added object.

Ideas?

Comment: how do you get `formattedName` and what does `.autoCompletefb()` do? Also, have you tried `alert("#" + formattedName);` to see if you're getting the result you want?

Comment: had a typo from copy-n-paste. Using same variable in code, fixed up.
autoCompletefb() is from here http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the input an ID of the contents of the `name` variable and selecting an element with an id of the contents of the `formattedName` variable. What is the difference between the two? The code would work if they are the same.

Besides that, you have a JS error near the end of the append() call:

```
value = \"\" />";+ "</li>");
```

Probably want it to be:

```
value='' /></li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a spare semicolon in the wrong place

```
 $("#ulList").append("<li><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close remove\"/><em class=\"selectedWord\">" + selectedWord + "</em><input class=\"acf acfb-input ac_input\" type=\"text\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\" value = \"\" />" + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dynamically added input item is fully loaded before trying to access it on the page.  also, do you have a variable mixup?  You use "name" as a variable in the first line as "formattedName" as the variable in the second line.

Comment: How would one assure the item is fully loaded before attempting to access it?

Comment: Can you use the onload event of the dynamically added textbox to execute a javascript function which in turn accesses that textbox?