# Applying jQuery function to dynamically added item

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is basically [the same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240184/applying-jquery-function-to-dynamically-added-item) (which never got properly answered).

How can I use a jQuery function on an item I add dynamically?

Specifically, I want to use the [jquery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) on a table that I load on the page dynamically, after the user does something.

Here's my code:

```
 results_html += "<table id='results' class='tablesorter><thead>"; 
 [My table contents go here, ommitted for this question]
 results_html += "</tbody></table>";
 $('#book_results').html(results_html);
 $("#results").tablesorter();
```

There are no JS errors on the page, but the tablesorter functions aren't being applied. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that code, I can only think of two reasons for that not working:

1. If `results` isn't a unique ID on the page.
2. If the typo in the opening line is actually in your code (you're missing the closing `'` after the 'tablesorter' class:

   ```
   results_html += "<table id='results' class='tablesorter><thead>"; 
                                                       // ^-- here
   ```

Fundamentally, it works: http://jsbin.com/ikebu4/2 That doesn't look like much because I haven't included any of the table sorter CSS, but it's functional if you click the column headers. Basically there's a pre-existing table, and then a button to add one dynamically. The tablesorter stuff works for both.

Comment: My code is actually a bit different from the example (longer). But I don't see any errors in Firebug, even with strict javascript warnings switched on. Hmm...

Comment: @AP257: Does the typo exist in the real code? If so, Firefox may not be generating the DOM structure you expect (and that TableSorter needs).

Comment: sorry - no, it's not in the real code. There is quite a lot of extra code in the middle of the table, but I don't see any obvious errors, and Firebug isn't showing me any errors (though that could be a Firebug problem, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Tablesorter has a trigger function, which you can call to add a tablesorter to a dynamically added element. See the [Ajax example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html) here. Something like this should work for you:

```
 $("#results").tablesorter(); 
 $("#results").trigger("update");
```

Sometimes you need to call `$("#results").trigger("appendCache");`. I haven't found out why yet.

Comment: Should he need it? The example I linked in my answer doesn't have it, and works fine.

Comment: @T.J. Strange, i've used tablesorter several times and haven't been able to do what you do. Maybe there is an update which fixes this. @AP257 Do you have the latest version?